# Is MongoDB point in time recovery only possible with OpLogs?

Tags: mongodb

For MongoDB version 3+

We are using MongoDB as a single stand-alone instance.  I discovered I can't create a point in time recovery without building a single node replica so I can take advantage of the oplogs to "replay transactions" for point in time recovery. I've done some testing making a single node replica I seem to be able to restore to a specific time.

Is there an alternative with a stand-alone mongodb to get point in time recovery or do I need to convert it to a single node replca.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By point-in-time I assume you mean arbitrary point-in-time.  You can get a backup up to a particular point by taking a filesystem snapshot at that point, but you can't roll that snapshot forward arbitrarily (by say 10 seconds) to another point without taking another snapshot, or having an oplog.

Basically, yes, you will need an oplog (and hence a single node replica set at a minimum) to be able to recover your data to a specific point in time.  The oplog needs to be big enough to cover all operations between your backup/snapshot to the point in time you wish to recover.

For example, if you take backups every 24 hours then you will need an oplog to cover at least 24 hours worth of operations in order to be able to restore to any point in that day.  The more often you take backups, the smaller you can make your oplog while retaining the capability.

Comment: Thanks Adam for validating my question! Much appreciated.